# Can you "split" a determinant along multiple rows or columns?

Tags: determinant

I know that a matrix A given by: $$ \begin{vmatrix} (a + x) & (b + y) & (c + z) \\\ p & q & r \\\ s & t & u \end{vmatrix} $$ can be split as $$ \begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\\ p & q & r \\\ s & t & u \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} x & y & z \\\ p & q & r \\\ s&t&u \end{vmatrix} $$.

Can we do something like this? If a matrix B is given by: $$ \begin{vmatrix} a + x & b + y & c + z \\\ p + d & q + e & r + f \\\ s + h & t + i & u + j \end{vmatrix} $$ Can we split it into:

$$ \begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\\ p & q & r \\\ s & t & u \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} x & y & z \\\ d & e & f \\\ s&t&u \end{vmatrix} $$.

Comment: No.  The determinant operator is not a linear function.

Comment: Its not quite that simple, apply your first rule one row at a time to learn the correct formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that it is possible, but its not as simple as the formula you proposed.

Here is the correct calculation :

$$ \begin{vmatrix} a + x & b + y & c + z \\\ p + d & q + e & r + f \\\ s + h & t + i & u + j \end{vmatrix} $$

$$= \begin{vmatrix}  x &  y &  z \\\ p + d & q + e & r + f \\\ s + h & t + i & u + j \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} a  & b  & c  \\\ p + d & q + e & r + f \\\ s + h & t + i & u + j \end{vmatrix} $$

$$= \begin{vmatrix}  x &  y &  z \\\  d &  e &  f \\\ s + h & t + i & u + j \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}  x &  y &  z \\\ p  & q  & r  \\\ s + h & t + i & u + j \end{vmatrix}
 +  \begin{vmatrix} a  & b  & c  \\\  d & e &  f \\\ s + h & t + i & u + j \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} a  & b  & c  \\\ p  & q  & r  \\\ s + h & t + i & u + j \end{vmatrix} $$

$$= \begin{vmatrix}  x &  y &  z \\\  d &  e &  f \\\ s  & t & u  \end{vmatrix}
+ \begin{vmatrix}  x &  y &  z \\\  d &  e &  f \\\ h & i &  j \end{vmatrix}
 + \begin{vmatrix}  x &  y &  z \\\ p  & q  & r  \\\ s  & t  & u  \end{vmatrix}
 + \begin{vmatrix}  x &  y &  z \\\ p  & q  & r  \\\ h & i &  j \end{vmatrix}
 +  \begin{vmatrix} a  & b  & c  \\\  d & e &  f \\\ s & t  & u  \end{vmatrix}
 +  \begin{vmatrix} a  & b  & c  \\\  d & e &  f \\\  h &  i &  j \end{vmatrix}
 + \begin{vmatrix} a  & b  & c  \\\ p  & q  & r  \\\ s  & t  & u  \end{vmatrix}
 + \begin{vmatrix} a  & b  & c  \\\ p  & q  & r  \\\ h & i &  j \end{vmatrix} 
 $$

Comment: Thank you. So we're supposed to do it one at a time, and not together.